# Encoding and decoding a bitmap to base64, the final bitmap is just all black

Tags: java, android, bitmap, base64

I have an app that has images that need to be saved when a user exits out. I figured I would take the bitmaps and store them in a database as a base64 string, so I found the following methods online to do so. However, after decoding the base64 string back to a bitmap and displaying it, it's just all black and does not resemble the original picture. I can't figure out why this is.

```
public static String encodeTobase64(Bitmap image)
{
    Bitmap immagex=image;
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
    immagex.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
    String imageEncoded = Base64.encodeToString(b,Base64.DEFAULT);

    Log.e("LOOK", imageEncoded);
    return imageEncoded;
}
public static Bitmap decodeBase64(String input) 
{
    byte[] decodedByte = Base64.decode(input, 0);
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedByte, 0, decodedByte.length); 
}
```

Comment: I think your strategy is OK, but I would check things like the dimensions of the original bitmap, the length of the encoded byte array, and the length of the decoded byte array.

Comment: My encoded byte array size was 1161 and my decoded was 1161 as well.

Comment: Dimensions of the bitmap?

Comment: @DougStevenson 150dp x 50dp

Comment: The numbers look reasonable I guess.  You could try PNG encoding as well. Anyway, most databases can store binary data (blob) so you don't have to convert to base64.

Comment: @DougStevenson Thanks for sticking with me, that's interesting. Maybe I will look into storing it as a blob? But first I will try PNG encoding. EDIT: IT WORKED!

Answer (score 0):

(I don't have comment permission.. so I am asking here)

In encode method, why you use JPG compress?

I think just simple bitmap-> base64 string.

And base64 string -> bitmap would be fine.

But I dont't understand why there is JPEG compress

Comment: Hm, I guess that's a good question. I don't really know much about encoding and decoding. How could I change it to what you recommend?

Comment: I hope this page helps..   http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/5950/how-to-convert-from-bitmap-to-byte-without-bitmap-compress